# xml2 related "undefiened reference to...." errors in compiling "libaiml-0.6"

Tags: error-handling, xml-parsing, undefined-reference

I have installed `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` but I don't know why do I get these error message when I want to `make` the `libaiml` AIML interpreter:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/m/libaiml'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/m/libaiml/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/m/libaiml/src'
Making all in test_app
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/m/libaiml/test_app'
Making all in aiml
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/m/libaiml/test_app/aiml'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/m/libaiml/test_app/aiml'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/m/libaiml/test_app'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX --mode=link g++ -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic `xml2-config --cflags` -g -O2   -o test_app `xml2-config --libs` main.o ../src/libaiml.a  -lstd_utils 
g++ -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic -I/usr/include/libxml2 -g -O2 -o test_app main.o  -lxml2 ../src/libaiml.a -lstd_utils
../src/libaiml.a(user_manager.o): In function `aiml::cUserManager::cUserManager(aiml::cCore&)':
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:32: undefined reference to `xmlNewParserCtxt'
../src/libaiml.a(user_manager.o): In function `aiml::cUserManager::~cUserManager()':
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:36: undefined reference to `xmlFreeParserCtxt'
../src/libaiml.a(user_manager.o): In function `aiml::cUserManager::save(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:101: undefined reference to `xmlNewTextWriterFilename'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:104: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterSetIndent'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:105: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterSetIndentString'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:108: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterStartDocument'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:109: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterStartElement'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:113: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterStartElement'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:114: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:118: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterStartElement'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:119: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:120: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterWriteCDATA'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:121: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterEndElement'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:123: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterEndElement'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:126: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterEndElement'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:127: undefined reference to `xmlTextWriterEndDocument'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:138: undefined reference to `xmlFreeTextWriter'
../src/libaiml.a(user_manager.o): In function `aiml::cUserManager::load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:51: undefined reference to `xmlCtxtReadFile'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:55: undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement'
/home/m/libaiml/src/user_manager.cpp:93: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
../src/libaiml.a(config_parser.o): In function `aiml::cConfigParser::cConfigParser(aiml::cCore&)':
/home/m/libaiml/src/config_parser.cpp:38: undefined reference to `xmlNewParserCtxt'
../src/libaiml.a(config_parser.o): In function `aiml::cConfigParser::~cConfigParser()':
/home/m/libaiml/src/config_parser.cpp:42: undefined reference to `xmlFreeParserCtxt'
../src/libaiml.a(config_parser.o): In function `aiml::cConfigParser::load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)':
/home/m/libaiml/src/config_parser.cpp:51: undefined reference to `xmlCtxtReadFile'
/home/m/libaiml/src/config_parser.cpp:55: undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement'
/home/m/libaiml/src/config_parser.cpp:78: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
../src/libaiml.a(aiml_parser.o): In function `aiml::AIMLparser::onError()':
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:120: undefined reference to `xmlCtxtGetLastError'
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:120: undefined reference to `xmlCtxtGetLastError'
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:124: undefined reference to `xmlStopParser'
../src/libaiml.a(aiml_parser.o): In function `aiml::AIMLparser::onFatalError()':
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:130: undefined reference to `xmlCtxtGetLastError'
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:130: undefined reference to `xmlCtxtGetLastError'
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:134: undefined reference to `xmlStopParser'
../src/libaiml.a(aiml_parser.o): In function `aiml::AIMLparser::startElement(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)':
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:211: undefined reference to `xmlStopParser'
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:296: undefined reference to `xmlStopParser'
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:337: undefined reference to `xmlStopParser'
../src/libaiml.a(aiml_parser.o): In function `aiml::AIMLparser::parse(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool)':
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:88: undefined reference to `xmlCreateFileParserCtxt'
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:94: undefined reference to `xmlParseDocument'
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:102: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
/home/m/libaiml/src/aiml_parser.cpp:103: undefined reference to `xmlFreeParserCtxt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:225: recipe for target 'test_app' failed
make[3]: *** [test_app] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/m/libaiml/test_app'
Makefile:274: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/m/libaiml/test_app'
Makefile:250: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/m/libaiml'
Makefile:179: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```